# How to load multiple templates from handlebars.js partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache, rich-client-platform

Is there an easy way to load a partial, with multiple templates in it, using handlebars.js, just like you can do it using mustache.js and the [jQuery plugin from "jonnyreeves"](https://github.com/jonnyreeves/jquery-Mustache)

e.g:

```
$.Mustache.load('./templates/greetings.htm').done(function () {
    $('body').mustache('simple-hello', viewData);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html) you need to register each partial, using `Handlebars.registerPartial`

You can do it like this:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Get template from server
  $.get("http://example.com/template.html").done(function(response) {
    var content = $($.parseHTML(response));

    //Compile main template
    var template = Handlebars.compile(content.filter("#test-template").html());

    //You need to register each partial
    Handlebars.registerPartial({
      foo: content.filter("#foo-partial").html(),
      bar: content.filter("#bar-partial").html()
    });

    //Your data
    var data = {
      "test": [{
        foo: "Foo",
        "foo_bar": "Foo-Bar",
        bar: "Bar",
        bar_foo: "Bar-Foo"
      }, {
        foo: "Foo2",
        "foo_bar": "Foo-Bar2",
        bar: "Bar2",
        bar_foo: "Bar-Foo2"
      }]
    };


    document.body.innerHTML = template(data);

  });

});
```

**template.html**

```
<!-- template.html -->
<script id="test-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each test}}
    {{> foo}}
    {{> bar}}
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="foo-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="foo">
    <h2>{{foo}}</h2>
    <div class="foo_bar">{{foo_bar}}</div>
  </div>
</script>

<script id="bar-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="bar">
    <h2>{{bar}}</h2>
    <div class="bar_foo">{{bar_foo}}</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much :) thats exactly the solution of my problem .
i think the missing link was this part
`content.filter("#test-template").html()`

Comment: Yes, that's the main difference, and the `registerPartial` part.