# How to dynamically create graphs with meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, graph, handlebars.js

I'm working on a project with `meteor` using handlebars (clearly), but ran into a problem, I need to dynamically graph data

so I'm using the `#each` to loop into all my events

---

---

```html
<ul class="collection">
            {{#each events}}
            {{#if currentUser}}
            <li class="collection-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s4">
                 {{topic}}
                        <canvas id="myChart" width = "500"></canvas>
```

the problem starts when there's more than 1 graph because the `id` of the canvas needs to be different each time, so can be accessed it on the JS file like this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
     
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        
    type: 'line',
        
    data: {
```

I'm new to `meteor` and `handlebars` and don't know if there's a way to give a different `id` to each `chart` or a different way to access to the `getelementbyid.getcontext`.
Hope I was clear and hope you can help me please

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037348/how-to-load-multiple-templates-from-handlebars-js-partial